# Mvvmcross Remove all fragments and add new. Contract failed - Fragment tag is null

Tags: android, navigation, mvvmcross

In the latest version of mvvmcross(4.4) bug appears. I want to add new fragment to the fragment manager, removing all other fragments. I implemented next code in overridden MvxFragmentsPresenter.ChangePresentation

```
rootActivity.SupportFragmentManager.PopBackStackImmediate(null, Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManager.PopBackStackInclusive);
this.Show(request);
```

But removed fragment is not deleted from SupportFragmentManager, it's just set to null. So when when after that I add another third fragment, it located at start of fragment list, not the end. And when I try to return to the first fragment, the second fragment crashes with Contract failed - Fragment tag is null error

e.g.
fragment A --> remove A and add B. --> add C(now C has zero index in Fragment list) --> add fragments D,E -> return to B(fragment C throw exception).
Is there any other way to remove fragment and add new?

Comment: It's seems, that sometimes tags for fragments are not saved(not sure why). Fixed this by adding overriden UniqueImmutableCacheTag, but want to know, what's the reason